# Alternative to apply in javascript

Tags: javascript, scope

I just read this article explaining how to use apply in javascript.
[javascript apply](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-apply-call-and-bind-methods-are-essential-for-javascript-professionals/)

In the section "Borrow Other Methods and Functions" it gives an example for calculating the average score, it defines two controllers, gameController and appController.

```
var gameController = {
scores : [20,34,55,46,77],
avgScore:null,
players: [
{name:'Tommy',playerID:987,age:23},
{name:'Paul',playerID:87,age:33}
]
}

var appController = {
scores:[900,845,809,950],
avgScore:null,
avg:function(){
    var sumOfScores = this.scores.reduce(function(prev,cur,index,array){
        return prev + cur
    })

    this.avgScore = sumOfScores / this.scores.length
    }
}

appController.avg.apply(gameController)
console.log(gameController.avgScore)
```

the avg function is defined with the this keyword, so using apply to redefine the scope by passing the controller, I understand the meaning and will know how to borrow method from other libraries.

I asked myself if is could write the avg function in a more "familiar way", so here is the code i want to compare:

```
var appController = {
scores:[900,845,809,950],
avgScore:null,
avg:function(arg){
    var sumOfScores = arg.scores.reduce(function(prev,cur,index,array){
        return prev + cur
    })

    return arg.avgScore = sumOfScores / arg.scores.length
}
```

}

```
console.log(appController.avg(gameController))
```

I have the same result, so why would you write function with the this keyword?What are the benefits?

Comment: `call`, `apply` and `bind` are useful methods when you want to change the execution context, pass parameters etc. to a function, but the given example doesn't really have any great benefit in using the `this` keyword, it's just an example that shows how you can change the "thisValue" with `apply`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The benefit of using `this` is that with the default binding to a caller you have

```
appController.avg();
```

Compare it to your version with explicit parameter

```
appController.avg( appController );
```

This looks bad and against good practices of object oriented design where objects have well defined responsibilities and methods have understandable signatures.

On the other hand, having this method yet elsewhere and passing a controller there would be ok:

```
controllerService.avg( appController );
```

Comment: sorry but did you say that my method is acceptable if i write a set of functions whose purpose are to be used as a "library",but that if i write "on the fly" a function, it is better to use apply?

Comment: @YvonHuynh: this is only the matter of your programming style. A code can be worse or better in terms of style but can behave in exactly the same way. What do you mean by "on th fly"?

Comment: "on the fly" i mean quick and dirty coding a function when i need it, against building an architectured codebase, hope this makes it clearer..

Answer (score 0):

As in many programming languages, there are many ways to solve a problem in javascript. There is no particular benefit in using `this` apart from being more object oriented.

In object oriented code, `this` is the context of the method, the primary object with which the behavior implemented in the method is associated with.

An arguably more elegant approach has been proposed in ES7 as the [bind operator](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:bind_operator).

Comment: i won't use apply for the sake of using apply, if i could use a simpler mehod i'd use that simpler method.If using apply helps me becoming a better programmer then i'd go for it. thanks for the link.